# Nginx does not keep nat source port

Tags: nginx, nat, port-forwarding

I'm trying to join my application with a translation port (nat) with the following url `https://myapp:11201/webapp` but Nginx does not keep the port translated and redirects url to: `https://myapp/webapp`

here is a part of the configuration:

```
     rewrite ^/$ https://$host:11201/Webapp Permanent;

     location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:8080;

     }
     location /Webapp/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:8080;
     }
```

thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: what's the webapp? Is it something developed by you or is it a standard cms/ecommerce/etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect to https://myapp/webapp is done by your webapp, not by nginx

Comment: it works by adding a "/"  at the end URL (https://myapp:11201/webapp/)

Comment: if you omit the trailing / the page is served by the first location {} block. If you add a / it's served by the second block. In your question, the two blocks are identical so I don't see how this problem could depend on nginx. The only explanation is that the nginx config in use is different from the one you posted.